# Python match word to word list after removing repeating characters

Tags: python, regex, nlp

I have a list of words with positive and negative sentiment e.g. `['happy', 'sad']`

Now when processing tweets I'm removing repeating characters like this (allowing only 2 repetitions):

```
happpppyyy -> happyy

saaad -> saad
```

The check if e.g. `saad` is part of the word list should now return `True` because it is similar to `sad`.

How can I implement this behaviour?

Comment: @PranavCBalan explanation?

Comment: @PranavCBalan:  that looks like (whisper) Perl to me.

Comment: Something to consider: I think it is probably unavoidable to have wrong matches: eg if saad should match sad, then should steep match step?

Comment: @AndreasGrivas yep it is a trade off, but I'm only dealing with words expressing emotions and there are not so many cases where something like this can happen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would build regular expressions dynamically turning a word:

```
happy
```

into

```
h+a+p+p+y+
```

Pass a list of "happy" words to this:

```
import re

re_list = [re.compile("".join(["{}+".format(c) for c in x])) for x in ['happy', 'glad']]
```

then test it (using `any` to return `True` if any happy regex matches:

```
for w in ["haaappy","saad","glaad"]:
    print(w,any(re.match(x,w) for x in re_list))
```

result:

```
haaappy True
saad False
glaad True
```

Comment: took me a while to understand that approach. I think it should bee sufficient engough for me; with this method I can actually skip the step to remove multiple characters